# how to set an integer property in another object from a tableviewcontroller

Tags: uitableview, exc-bad-access

i'm new to objective C and I'm trying...and trying to set an integer property on a model object from within the tableviewcontroller code.  Here is the top of the model object project.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface Project : NSObject
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger *selecto;
@end
```

and project.m is simply

```
#import "Project.h"
@implementation Project
@synthesize selecto;
@end
```

I have added an instance of project into an array using code in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method of the app delegate like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
projects = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:20];
Project *project = [[Project alloc] init];
project.selecto = 0;
[projects addObject:project];
return YES;
}
```

and the didselectmethod of the tableViewControler is:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
int selectedRow = [indexPath row];
Project *pro = [projects objectAtIndex:selectedRow] ;
*pro.selecto = 1;//errors here with exc_bad_access code=2 
}
```

whenever I run it it freezes on assigning the property selecto and I get a n error :
exc_bad_access code=2 
probably a simple newbie question - but I spent about 8 hours trying to figure this out...maybe I need a different hobby...

Comment: Thanks that did it...right there in front of me the whole time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your property `selecto` is a POINTER to a long integer, and in  `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` you set it to 0, i.e. `nil`. In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`, you are trying to set to 1 whatever selecto points to.
Just use `@property (nonatomic) NSInteger selecto;` and `pro.selecto = 1;` instead.